# High performance lookup table in Fortran

Tags: performance, fortran, intel-fortran

Part of my simulation code requires me to find the opacity for a given density and temperature. There is no analytic relation for this; the standard method is to use 2D array where the `opacity(i,j)` would correspond to the opacity for `density(i)` and `temperature(j)`, and run a bilinear interpolation to find the exact opacity.

This is the bottleneck in my group's code currently - each time step, the interpolation routine is called roughly 100 million times for different densities and temperatures, and it accounts for about 20% of the runtime. The current code is shown below - are there any tricks I could use to improve it? I use Intel Fortran 16, with the options `-O3 -xavx -mcmodel=medium`

```
function smoothopc(den, temp, ig, opc, rhoT)

    implicit none
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: den,temp 
    integer,intent(in) :: ig
    real(kind=8), intent(in), dimension(1:50, 1:50, 1:52) :: opc
    real(kind=8), intent(in), dimension(1:50, 1:2) :: rhoT

    real(kind=8) :: rho, te, smoothopc, r1, r2, t1, t2, &
            interpolation, denominator, a, b, c, d, opc11, &
            opc12, opc21, opc22, t, tp, r, rp

    integer :: rid,tid,i

    rho = den * 1d - 3          !g/cc
    te = temp / (1.6d - 19)     !eV
    tid = -1
    rid = -1
    do i = 1, 49
        r = rhoT(i, 1)
        rp = rhoT(i + 1, 1)
        t = rhoT(i, 2)
        tp = rhoT(i + 1, 2)
        if (rho .ge. r) then
            rid = i
        endif

        if (te .ge. t) then
            tid = i
        endif
    enddo

    r1 = rhoT(rid, 1)
    r2 = rhoT(rid + 1, 1)
    t1 = rhoT(tid, 2)
    t2 = rhoT(tid + 1, 2)
    opc11 = opc(rid, tid, ig + 4)
    opc12 = opc(rid, tid + 1, ig + 4)
    opc21 = opc(rid + 1, tid, ig + 4)
    opc22 = opc(rid + 1, tid + 1, ig + 4)

    denominator = (r2 - r1) * (t2 - t1)
    a = r2 - rho
    b = rho - r1
    c = t2 - te
    d = te - t1

    interpolation = a * (c * opc11 + d * opc12) + b * &
            (c * opc21 + d * opc22)

    smoothopc = interpolation / denominator

    return

end function smoothopc
```

Comment: Have you tried to profile this function to find a bottleneck here? It is almost impossible for us to test anything without having a code to call it with representative data. And using consistent indentation would help a lot to see the structure of your code. Note that `kind=8` is ugly and not portable.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to profile a function line by line - I used gprof to identify this function as the bottleneck in the overall code, but how do I get more information about this function specifically? I'm not a huge fan of `real(kind=8)` either, but I have to work with what I was given!

Comment: There are profilers which profile individual lines like my favourite Oracle Performance Analyzer (works with gfortran too). Or perhaps Intel vTune Amplifier should be included in your Intel Fortran, learn to use it. And *please*, fix the indentation, the code looks really bad.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are doing a loop through the whole of `rhoT` to find indices that you use afterwards to find values in `opc`.

If the columns of `rhoT` are sorted, it may be faster to write a binary search instead (there is an overhead, so you will have to test).

Also, I don't quite understand your condition to assign `rid` and `tid` (it would seem logical that you assign rid only if `r <= rho < rp`). I may be missing something about how `rhoT` is built.

---

A trick you might try: convert `rho*M` to an integer, where M may be for instance a power of 2 or 10 (multiply by 1000 to get 3 digits of precision). The value rounded to an integer would be an index into an array whose elements are the correct (or nearest) values of `rid`. Even if you do not get the correct `rid`, you may have a much smaller range to check. If the scale is not linear, you may transform `rho` first.

---

Another possible trick: store the previous `rid` and `tid` indices. If the calls follow a rather continuous evolution, the new indices will likely be near the previous ones. But if your code has to be paralellized at some point, it's not a good idea as this introduces sequential dependences between calls.

Comment: Welcome. I very rarely edit someone else's answers, but I believe in this case it is much clearer to mark entities which are from OP's code (variable names, function names) as code, so that one does not wonder about what a word rid is. You may easily revoke the edit if you disagree.